# How to delete specific words from char array?

Tags: c

So my task is from char array delete these words which starts and ends with the same letter. And at this point my program crashes. 
Here is my function:

```
void RemoveSame(char * start) {
  int i, j, first, last, k;
  for (i = 1; i < LINE_LENGTH; i++) {
    if ( * (start + i) != ' ') {
      first = * (start + i);
      for (j = i; j < LINE_LENGTH; j++) {
        if ( * (start + i + j + 1) == ' ') {
          last = * (start + i + j);
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }

    }
    for (; i != j; i++) {
      k = j - i; 
      * (start + k) = "\0";
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my full code http://pasted.co/22566eb6

Comment: `* (start + k) = "\0";` --> `* (start + k) = '\0';` notice single quotes.

Comment: Change stuff like `* (start + i)` to `start[i]` - Makes the code more readable

Comment: Also the index of arrays start from 0 not 1

Comment: It would be helpful to see your whole code, so we can see how you are using this function.

Comment: http://pasted.co/22566eb6

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned:

changing `* (start + i)` to `start[i]` improves readability

`"\0"` should be `'\0'` or simply 0 - in c, double quotes are used to represent strings, and strings are actually memory addresses.

array indexes start from 0

Also keep in mind that strings write in clear in the source (ex: "abcba this is a string") are constant strings (const char*) and must be copied to other location in order to modify them.

```
void RemoveSame(char * start) {
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; start[i];) { // advance while haven't reached the string's end
        if (start[i] != ' ') {
            for (j = i + 1; ; ++j) {
                if (start[j] == ' ' || !start[j]) { // advance until I find a word
                    if (start[i] == start[j - 1]) {
                        for (k = i; (start[k] = start[k + j - i]); ++k); // delete word
                    }
                    else {
                        i = j;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters the code is so bad formatted that it is difficult to understand what it does.

It is not clear why the outer loop starts from 1.
The inner loop

```
  for (j = i; j < LINE_LENGTH; j++) {
    if ( * (start + i + j + 1) == ' ') {
      last = * (start + i + j);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
```

does not make any sense.

This loop

```
for (; i != j; i++) {
  k = j - i; 
  * (start + k) = "\0";
}
```

also does not make sense and moreover in this statement

```
  * (start + k) = "\0";
```

you are trying to assign an object of type `char` with a value of type `char *`. The compiler should issue here a diagnostic message.

It is also unclear why you do not use standard C functions.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   100

char * remove_words( char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    char *t = s;

    while ( *t )
    {
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*t ) ) ++t;

        char *last = t;

        if ( *last++ )
        {
            while ( *last && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*last ) ) ++last;

            if ( t[0] == last[-1] ) memmove( t, last, n - ( last -t ) + 1 );
            else t = last;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        char s[N];

        printf( "Input a sentence: (Enter - exit): " );

        if ( fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin ) == NULL || s[0] == '\n' ) break;

        s[ strcspn( s, "\n") ] = '\0';

        puts( s );

        puts( remove_words( s ) );

        printf( "\n" );     
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Input a sentence: (Enter - exit): ab aba abc abcbca dd d
ab aba abc abcbca dd d
ab  abc   

Input a sentence: (Enter - exit):
```

Another approach is to delete also blanks that follow the word that must be deleted. And it is more efficient than the first approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   100

char * remove_words( char *s )
{
    char *destination = s;

    //  for starters skip leading blands
    while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*destination ) ) ++destination;

    char *source = destination;

    while ( *source )
    {
        char *last = source;

        if ( *last++ )
        {
            while ( *last && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*last ) ) ++last;

            char *blank_tail = last;

            while ( isblank( ( unsigned char )*blank_tail ) ) ++blank_tail;

            if ( source[0] != last[-1] )
            {
                //  copy valid word to the destination
                if ( destination != source )
                {
                    memmove( destination, source, blank_tail - source );
                }
                destination += blank_tail - source;
            }

            source = blank_tail;
        }
    }

    *destination = '\0';

    return s;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        char s[N];

        printf( "Input a sentence: (Enter - exit): " );

        if ( fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin ) == NULL || s[0] == '\n' ) break;

        s[ strcspn( s, "\n") ] = '\0';

        puts( s );

        puts( remove_words( s ) );

        printf( "\n" );     
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the same way as it is shown abobe

```
Input a sentence: (Enter - exit): ab aba abc abcbca dd d
ab aba abc abcbca dd d
ab abc 

Input a sentence: (Enter - exit):
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *RemoveSame(char *str) {
    char *from, *to, *p;
    from = to = str;
    while(*from){
        if(isspace((unsigned char)*from)){//pre spaces copy before processing a word
            *to++ = *from++;
            continue;
        }
        p = from;//top of word
        while(*p && !isspace((unsigned char)*p))
            ++p;
        if(*from == p[-1])//top == end
            from = p;//skip
        else {
            while(*from && !isspace((unsigned char)*from))
                *to++ = *from++;//copy
        }
    }
    *to = 0;
    return str;
}

int main(void) {
    char sentence[] = "madam adam madam ada adam eve";
    printf("'%s'\n", RemoveSame(sentence));

}
```

Comment: Why this way of code does not find enough spaces? http://ideone.com/fSD8cv

Comment: http://ideone.com/5m79CH
So first it asks the maximum length of file name. 
Then asks to write a file from which program reads a char array and then asks output file name.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `RemoveSame()` has multiple problems:

- `i` should start at `0`
- `j` should start at `1`.  You are accessing characters much too far into the string with `start[i + j + 1]`
- you should stop at the `'\0'`
- you never copy the characters of the words you wish to keep
- setting the rest of the string to `0` seems unnecessary, but in any case you should use the null character `'\0'` instead of an empty string `"\0"`

Here is a corrected version:

```
void RemoveSame(char *str) {
    int i, j, to = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0';) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            str[to++] = str[i++];
            continue;
        }
        for (j = 1; str[i + j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (str[i + j] == ' ')
                break;
        }
        if (str[i] == str[i + j - 1]) {
            /* skip the word */
            i += j;
            continue;
        }
        for (; j > 0; j--) {
            str[to++] = str[i++];
        }
    }
    str[to] = '\0';  /* set the null terminator */
}
```

Notes:

- `str` is a more explicit name for a string than `start`.
- using the array notation `str[i]` is much more readable than `*(str + i)`.
- the spaces before or after the removed word should probably be removed too.

There are other problems in your code:

- `scanf("%s", &readerName);` is incorrect, use `scanf("%s", readerName);` instead.
- allocating `line` this way: `line = calloc(FILE_NAME_LENGTH, FILE_NAME_LENGTH * sizeof(char))` is incorrect, use an automatic array instead: `char line[LINE_LENGTH];`
- `while (!feof(reader))` is always wrong.  Use `while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, reader))` instead.
- `WriteLine()` should stop at the first `'\0'`.
- you should use `'\0'` for the null character, not `NULL` as in `*(start + i) != NULL`